# Shipping by Product

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

Does anyone know if there is a way to determine the cost of shipping as a product vs. destination? Basically I need the price of shipping various depending on the destination and by product or should vary according to product category.

[original post]
*Qualcuno sa se esiste un modo per stabilire il costo della spedizione come prodotto vs destinazione?
In pratica ho bisogno che il prezzo della spedizione vari in base alla destinazione e in base al prodotto oppure deve variare in base a prodotto e categoria.*

Comment: Please post your question in English

Answer (score 3):

There is but it's not default in Magento.

There are a couple of modules out there that offer matrix rate shipping like the ones from WebShopApps that allow you to specify shipping rate based on product and/or destination. They're paid but you can contact them via the website to ask if the module fits your specific needs. As far as I can tell it should

Comment: have you used translator :)

Comment: @AmitBera yup, my Italian is pretty rusty ;)

Comment: good :).............

Comment: @SanderMangel Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps matrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate.

Comment: Hi @zus I'm afraid I do not know that. Maybe its in their documentation

Comment: Anyone knows how to give free shipping using Webshopapps  Matrix Rates in SHopping Cart Pricing rule?